# Need help to split a string by delimiter (and keep the delimiter in the token list)

Tags: c, string, split

I want to split a string by a delimiter and keep the delimiter in the token list

I have a function that do the same thing as strtok but with a string delimiter (instead of a set of chars) but it doesn't keep the delimiter and can't take an array of delimiters as argument

This is a function that split a string into tokens as `strtok` does but taking a delimiter

```c
static char *strtokstr(char *str, char *delimiter)
{
    static char *string;
    char *end;
    char *ret;

    if (str != NULL)
        string = str;
    if (string == NULL)
        return string;
    end = strstr(string, delimiter);
    if (end == NULL) {
        char *ret = string;
        string = NULL;
        return ret;
    }
    ret = string;
    *end = '\0';
    string = end + strlen(delimiter);
    return ret;
}
```

I want to have a `char **split(char *str, char **delimiters_list)` that split a string by a set of delimiters and keep the delimiter in the token list

I think I also need a function to count the number of tokens so i can `malloc` the return of my `split` function

// `delimiters` is an array containing `["&&", "||" and NULL]`
`split("ls > file&&foo || bar", delimiters)` should return an array containing `["ls > file", "&&", "foo ", "||", " bar"]`

How that can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a memory error here :

```
static char *string;

if (str != NULL)
    string = str;
if (string == NULL)
    return string;
```

If `str`is NULL, string is not initialised and you use a uninitialised value in comparaison.

if you want copy a string, you must use the `strdup` function, the `=` will just copy the pointer and not the pointer content.

---

And here a way to do it :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *get_delimiters(char *str, char **delims)
{
  for (int i = 0; delims[i]; i++)
    if (!strncmp(str, delims[i], strlen(delims[i])))
      return delims[i];
  return NULL;
}

char **split(char *str, char **delimiters)
{
  char *string = strdup(str);
  char **result = NULL;
  int n = 0;
  char *delim = NULL;

  for (int i = 0; string[i]; i++)
    if (get_delimiters(string + i, delimiters))
      n++;
  result = malloc((n * 2 + 2) * sizeof(char *));
  if (!result)
    return NULL;
  result[0] = string;
  n = 1;
  for (int i = 0; string[i]; i++) {
    delim = get_delimiters(string + i, delimiters);
    if (delim) {
      string[i] = '\0';
      result[n++] = delim;
      result[n++] = string + i + strlen(delim);
    }
  }
  result[n] = NULL;
  return result;
}
```

result :

> [0] 'ls > file'
>   [1] '&&'
>   [2] 'foo '
>   [3] '||'
>   [4] ' bar'

remember `result` and `string` are malloced, so you must free the `result` and `result[0]`

Comment: Thank you for help !
Your function have a strange behaviour when deimiter is reapeated: 
`"foo &&& bar"` --> `[foo ][&&][& bar][&&][ bar]`
`"foo &&&& bar"` --> `[foo ][&&][][&&][& bar][&&][ bar]`
But i can workaround that by preprocessing the user input so it's not a problem ^^

Comment: Just a question: Assuming that `result` is the return of `split`, I have to free `result` or `result` and `result[i]` (for i++ until result[i] == NULL) ?

Comment: you have to free each varriable allocated with `malloc`, so you have to free `result` AND `result[0]` (because `strdup` use `malloc`).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char **split(char *str, char **delimiters, int number_of_delimiters, int *number_of_rows_in_return_array);

int main()
{

    char **split_str;
    char *delimiters[] = {
        "&&",
        "||"
    };


    int rows_in_returned_array;

    split_str = split("ls > file&&foo || bar && abc ||pqwe", delimiters, 2 , &rows_in_returned_array);

    int i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < rows_in_returned_array  ; ++i)
    {
        printf("\n%s\n", split_str[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}


char **split(char *str, char **delimiters, int number_of_delimiters, int *number_of_rows_in_return_array)
{
    //temporary storage for array to be returned
    char temp_store[100][200];
    int row = 0;//row size of array that will be returned

    char **split_str;

    int i, j, k, l, mark = 0;
    char temp[100];

    for (i = 0 ; str[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
    {

        //Iterating through all delimiters to check if any is str
        for (j = 0 ; j < number_of_delimiters ; ++j )
        {
            l = i;

            for (k = 0 ; delimiters[j][k] != '\0' ; ++k)
            {
                if (str[i] != delimiters[j][k])
                {
                    break;
                }

                ++l;
            }

            //This means delimiter is in string
            if (delimiters[j][k] == '\0')
            {
                //store the string before delimiter
                strcpy(temp_store[row], &str[mark]);
                temp_store[row ++][i - mark] = '\0';

                //store string after delimiter
                strcpy(temp_store[row], &str[i]);
                temp_store[row ++][k] = '\0';

                //mark index where this delimiter ended
                mark = l;

                //Set i to where delimiter ends and break so that outermost loop
                //can iterate from where delimiter ends
                i = l - 1;

                break;

            }

        }
    }

    //store the string remaining
    strcpy(temp_store[row++], &str[mark]);

    //Allocate the split_str and store temp_store into it
    split_str = (char **)malloc(row * sizeof(char *));
    for (i=0 ; i < row; i++)
    {
        split_str[i] = (char *)malloc(200 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(split_str[i], temp_store[i]);
    }

    *number_of_rows_in_return_array = row;

    return split_str;

}
```

This should probably work. Note that I have passed `int * number_of_rows_in_return_array` by ref because we need to know the row size of the retuned array.

Answer (score 0):

I went into abstraction. First I created a "sentence" library, that allows for manipulating NULL terminated list of strings (`char*`). I wrote some initial accessors (`sentence_init`, `sentence_size`, `sentence_free`, `sentence_add_str` etc.).

Then I went to `split`, witch becomes really, really easy then - if a delimeter is found, add the string up the delimeter to the sentence and add the delimeter to the sentence. Then increment the string pointer position. If the delimeter is not found, add the remaining string to the sentence.

There is a real problem with double pointers tho, because `char **` is not implicitly convertible to `const char **`. For production code, I would probably aim to refactor the code, and try to take `const`-correctness into account.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/*
 * sentence - list of words
 */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------- */

// if this would be production code, I think I would go with a
// struct word_t { char *word; }; struct sentence_t { struct word_t *words; };
// Note: when sentence_add_* fail - they free *EVERYTHING*, so it doesn't work like realloc
// shared_ptr? Never heard of it.

char **sentence_init(void) {
    return NULL;
}

size_t sentence_size(char * const *t) {
    if (t == NULL) return 0;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; t[i] != NULL; ++i) {
        continue;
    }
    return i;
}

void sentence_free(char * const *t) {
    if (t == NULL) return;
    for (char * const *i = t; *i != NULL; ++i) {
        free(*i);
    }
    free((void*)t);
}

void sentence_printex(char * const *t, const char *fmt1, const char *delim, const char *end) {
    for (char * const *i = t; *i != NULL; ++i) {
        printf(fmt1, *i);
        if (*(i + 1) != NULL) {
            printf(delim);
        }
    }
    printf(end);
}

void sentence_print(char * const *t) {
    sentence_printex(t, "%s", " ", "\n");
}

void sentence_print_quote_words(char * const *t) {
    sentence_printex(t, "'%s'", " ", "\n");
}

bool sentence_cmp_const(const char * const *t, const char * const *other) {
    const char * const *t_i = t;
    const char * const *o_i = other;
    while (*t_i != NULL && o_i != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(*t_i, *o_i) != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        ++t_i;
        ++o_i;
    }
    return *t_i == NULL && *o_i == NULL;
}

// thet's always funny, because "dupa" in my language means "as*"
char **sentence_add_strdupped(char **t, char *strdupped) {
    const size_t n = sentence_size(t);
    const size_t add = 1 + 1;
    const size_t new_n = n + add;
    void * const pnt = realloc(t,  new_n * sizeof(char*));
    if (pnt == NULL) goto REALLOC_FAIL;

    // we have to have place for terminating NULL pointer
    assert(new_n >= 2);
    t = pnt;
    t[new_n - 2] = strdupped;
    t[new_n - 1] = NULL;

    // ownership of str goes to t
    return t;

    // ownership of str stays in the caller
    REALLOC_FAIL:
    sentence_free(t);
    return NULL;
}

char **sentence_add_strlened(char **t, const char *str, size_t len) {
    char *strdupped = malloc(len + 1);
    if (strdupped == NULL) goto MALLOC_FAIL;

    memcpy(strdupped, str, len);
    strdupped[len] = '\0';

    t = sentence_add_strdupped(t, strdupped);
    if (t == NULL) goto SENTENCE_ADD_STRDUPPED_FAIL;

    return t;

    SENTENCE_ADD_STRDUPPED_FAIL:
    free(strdupped);
    MALLOC_FAIL:
    sentence_free(t);
    return NULL;
}

char **sentence_add_str(char **t, const char *str) {
    const size_t str_len = strlen(str);
    return sentence_add_strlened(t, str, str_len);
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------- */

/**
 * Puff. Run strstr for each of the elements inside NULL delimeters dellist.
 * If any returns not NULL, return the pointer as returned by strstr
 * And fill dellist_found with the pointer inside dellist (can be NULL).
 * Finally! A 3 star award is mine!
 */
char *str_find_any_strings(const char *str,
        const char * const *dellist,
        const char * const * *dellist_found) {
    assert(str != NULL);
    assert(dellist != NULL);
    for (const char * const *i = &dellist[0]; *i != NULL; ++i) {

        const char *found = strstr(str, *i);
        if (found != NULL) {
            if (dellist_found != NULL) {
                *dellist_found = i;
            }
            // __UNCONST(found)
            return (char*)found;
        }

    }
    return NULL;
}

/**
 * Split the string str according to the list od delimeters dellist
 * @param str
 * @param dellist
 * @return returns a dictionary
 */
char **split(const char *str, const char * const *dellist) {
    assert(str != NULL);
    assert(dellist != NULL);

    char **sen = sentence_init();

    while (*str != '\0') {
        const char * const *del_pnt = NULL;
        const char *found = str_find_any_strings(str, dellist, &del_pnt);
        if (found == NULL) {
            // we don't want an empty string to be the last...
            if (*str != '\0') {
                sen = sentence_add_str(sen, str);
                if (sen == NULL) return NULL;
            }
            break;
        }

        // Puff, so a delimeter is found at &str[found - str]
        const size_t idx = found - str;
        sen = sentence_add_strlened(sen, str, idx);
        if (sen == NULL) return NULL;

        assert(del_pnt != NULL);
        const char *del = *del_pnt;
        assert(del != NULL);
        assert(*del != '\0');
        const size_t del_len = strlen(del);
        sen = sentence_add_strlened(sen, del, del_len);
        if (sen == NULL) return NULL;

        str += idx + del_len;
    }

    return sen;
}

int main()
{
    char **sentence = split("ls > file&&foo || bar", (const char*[]){"&&", "||", NULL});
    assert(sentence != NULL);
    sentence_print_quote_words(sentence);
    printf("cmp = %d\n", sentence_cmp_const((void*)sentence, (const char*[]){"ls > file", "&&", "foo ", "||", " bar", NULL}));
    sentence_free(sentence);

    return 0;
}
```

The program will output:

```
'ls > file' '&&' 'foo ' '||' ' bar'
cmp = 1
```