# String token segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, strtok

```
void infixToPostfix(char *infix)
{
    char postfix[100], tokens[20][20], *temptok;
    int i = 0;
    temptok = strtok(infix, "+-*/() ");
    tokens[i++][20] = *temptok;
    while (temptok != NULL)
    {
        temptok = strtok(NULL, "+-*/() ");
        tokens[i++][20] = *temptok;
        printf("%s ", *temptok);
    }
}
int main()
{
    char infix[100] = "5+7+8+10*100";
    /*printf("Please enter the infix expression: ");
    gets(infix);*/
    infixToPostfix(infix);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives me a segmentation fault when i try to tokenize my string. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `tokens[i++][20]` assigns outside the array. The valid indexes of the second dimension go from 0 to 19. But why are you assigning just one character of the token instead of copying the entire token?

Comment: How is that i am only accepting like 2 characters per token?

Comment: I think you want `strcpy(tokens[i++], temptok);`

Comment: `*temptok` is the one character that `temptok` points to, which is the first character of the token, equivalent to `temptok[0]`.

Comment: This isn't really a good way to tokenize, anyway. Don't you need to save the operators in the token array, in addition to the numbers between them?

Comment: aha i get you but i do still get an error which is "passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Comment: this is my first time learning tokens i wanna tokenize every number and each operator

Comment: `strtok()` leaves out the delimiters, it only tokenizes what's between them. You can't use it for this.

Comment: aha then how do you suggest i approach this?

Comment: A state machine is a common way to approach it.

Comment: question then say i wanna tokenize "1 + 5 * 7" using " " as a delimiter how do i do this?

Comment: `printf("%s ", *temptok);` should not have `*`. I got a warning from that, and it was causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: In that case you can use `strtok()`, since you don't need to include the space as a token. It's only a problem when the delimiter is also a token.

Comment: aha thank you. i am also getting a seg fault on this line "strcpy(tokens[i++][100], temptok);" why is that?

Comment: Get rid of `[100]`. `tokens[i++]` is a string, `tokens[i++][100]` is a single character, and it's outside the array bounds.

Comment: ok done but i got another problem here. when the string ends it gives a segmentation fault

Comment: i dont quite understand your question to be honest i plan on tokenizing then using a stack to switch to a postfix expression

Comment: Adding the temp token to the array can only be done if strtok doesn't return NULL.  So you need to check that by sticking the copy operation inside the loop: https://onlinegdb.com/hI_rIdwh4

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303807/need-help-to-split-a-string-by-delimiter-and-keep-the-delimiter-in-the-token-li